# SqlDataAdapter - combine stored procedure and Select statement with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Using a `SqlDataAdapter` (or other ASP.NET technique), is it possible to make a single SQL call to both a stored procedure and run a select statement? Both have parameters.

I know you can combine multiple select statements...

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT id FROM Table1 WHERE id=@myid; SELECT id FROM Table2", connection);
    cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",myid);
    cmd.Fill(ds);
}
```

And you can call a stored procedure in a similar way...

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter("myStoredProcedure", connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",myid);
    cmd.Fill(ds);
}
```

But I'd like to combine the two into a single call.

I need to keep the stored procedure and select statements separate. I do not want to combine them into a single stored procedure.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is the [exec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) function.

From the docs

> It Executes a command string or character string within a Transact-SQL
>   batch, or one of the following modules: system stored procedure,
>   user-defined stored procedure, CLR stored procedure, scalar-valued
>   user-defined function, or extended stored procedure.

So you could do this:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT id FROM Table1 WHERE id=@myid; Exec myStoredProcedure @myid", connection);
    cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myid",myid);
    cmd.Fill(ds);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Juan! So if I wanted to pass two parameters to my store procedure it would look like this... "Exec myStoredProcedure @myid, @myid2"

Also, what if one of those parameters was a User Defined Table Type?

Comment: Yes, you have to pass all the parameter required by the multi-statement command.